# expressjs layout with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, express

I want to use `expressjs` to serve an `angularjs` app, right now I set up the connection between express and angular using :

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

but I would like to draw the layout of index.ejs in expressjs and then have my angularjs site inside this layout.. so the default page is not in frontend but in express.

How can I achieve this if you can provide some tips or a simple example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a function in express that serves the Index. For example:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

In this case, when you access localhost:3000 you reach this action and are returned the index which has the angular app.

I recommend you take a look at [express-generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html). It sets up a base application where everything in place so it gets a lot easier to understand and move onwards.